# Для чего в assembler нужно определить байт (fasm)?

Tags: ассемблер

Для чего нужно определить байт и зачем в конце указать 0?

```
.data
Caption db 'Моя первая программа.',0
Text db 'Hello world!',0
```

P.S. у меня 32 битная архитектура.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для чего нужно определять байт - потому что код каждого символа строки в данном случае занимает 1 байт. Строка символов - это массив байт.

0 в данном случае обозначает конец строки. Если вы не добавите 0 после первой строки, то строки сольются, и данные начиная с адреса `Caption` можно будет проинтерпретировать как строку `'Моя первая программа.Hello world!'`.

Символ с кодом 0 - это разделитель строки, который "понимают", например, функции стандартной библиотеки Си и функции WinAPI.

Подробнее см. [Нуль-термирированная строка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Существуют и другие способы указания конца строки: например, под DOS функции вывода строк подразумевали, что строка оканчивается на символ `$`, что не очень удобно, если вы, например, захотите вывести этот символ.